Events cannot be set in the Application class XAML file
I wrote this code:
<Page
    x:Class="FinancialManager.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FinancialManager"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <StackPanel Padding="20" Margin="0,103,0,-103">
            <TextBox x:Name="DescriptionTextBox" PlaceholderText="Açıklama" />
            <TextBox x:Name="AmountTextBox" PlaceholderText="Tutar" />
            <Button Content="Gelir Ekle" Click="AddIncomeButton_Click" />
            <Button Content="Gider Ekle" Click="AddExpenseButton_Click" />
            <ListView x:Name="TransactionsListView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    
</Page>

and I get this error:

Events cannot be set in the Application class XAML file

I tried writing the code in a different way and resorted to AI models.

The current code cannot reproduce the error you mentioned. Did you add anything to the App.xaml.cs? Please provide [mre].
